# how to print user input into browser using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Quite simply, I want the user to enter details into a text box, hit a button and then it prints that below the box they entered in. so far I have this:

my JS function:

```
function funcKeyUp(){

    var name = document.getElementById("oldName");
    document.getElementById("newName").innerHTML = oldName;
}
```

my html:

```
Enter name: <input type="text" name="oldName">
<button type="button" onclick="funcKeyUp()"> submit name </button> <br>
<p id="newName"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are mistaken that you should assign **name** to the paragraph tag instead of **oldName**. Since oldName is the tag Name.

```
document.getElementById("newName").innerHTML = name;
```

Comment: May i know the reason why my answer is down voted. One who down voted please provide it.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted myself but I suspect it has something to do with this not being the most immediately obvious issue. I upvoted.

Comment: @JonathanGray :: Thanks for you immediate response.

Comment: just dumbass people downvoting stuff, why is my question down voted? didn't know how to solve a problem, attempted to solve it. couldnt. asked on a forum that deals with questions exactly of this nature. if i ever met these people, they'd leave without their hands.

Comment: p.s. thanks for the help, the button is still refusing to do anything when clicked

Answer (score 1):

Try `name.value` or add `.value` to the end of `getElementById("oldName")`

Comment: Also use ID and not name for the attribute

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript second line should be:

```
var oldName = document.getElementById("oldName").value;
```

And the html first line:

```
Enter name: <input type="text" id="oldName">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use:

```
Enter name: <input type="text" id="oldName">
<button type="button" onclick="funcKeyUp()"> submit name </button> <br>
<p id="newName"></p>
```

and

```
function funcKeyUp(){

    var name = document.getElementById("oldName").value;
    document.getElementById("newName").innerHTML = name;
}
```

this will do your job
Keep Learning :)

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the name as id.
This should work.

Add the id to the input box :

```
<input type="text" id="oldName" name="oldName">

var name = document.getElementById("oldName").value;
document.getElementById("newName").innerHTML = name;
```